# DynamoDB query 1 field greate than

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have games table.

To keep it simple, I will add only two fields for the question.

gameId:

deadlineToPlay:

I want to query for all games with deadlineToPlay > than today.

How would I set up the index for this?  I thought I could create an index with just deadlineToPlay, but if I understand correctly when querying on hashkey, it has to be exact value.  Can't use >.

I would also not like to use a scan, due to costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to workaround this would be to create or use an existing field which will have constant value (for example, field `hasDeadline` with value `true`).

Now you can create the table key like this: `hasDeadline` as HASH key and `deadlineToPlay` as SORT key (if the table is already created, you can define this key in a new GSI).

This way you will be able to query by `hasDeadline = true` and `deadlineToPlay > today`.